# Does Apache Camel work only with Apache CXF or Spring-WS?

Tags: spring, web-services, apache-camel, jax-rpc

I am trying to work on a PoC to replace an IBM WESB Proxy mediation (Exposed as a web service, Receives the soap request, Invokes different other Web Services based on the Soap Header passed in the request).

These web services are built using JAX-RPC and Spring framework running in WAS 7 container.

**Is it possible to use Camel for this usecase**? I don't want to migrate the underlying web services to CXF or SpringWS yet.

**Does Camel have any URI's to solve this purpose?** (like a web service adapter to call other non-CXF/non-SpringWS web services)

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See this for something similiar that you want to do:http://camel.apache.org/cxf-proxy-example.html Your question is not clear so I am not sure if you just going to expose some proxied services etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing - If it is a RPC /ENCODED web service then you CANNOT call it even with cxf.There are ways that you can modify the rpc wsdl to use doc/literal but I would not suggest using that approach.
The simplest way to do this if you do not want to use cxf component or spring-ws is to create a java bean to invoke the Axis web service using the generated stubs.